# NET8 MAUI ListView select item is orange

Tags: c#, android, maui

I was asking this question in the past and the answer I got was that this was a bug and it will be fixed with the NET8.

With the new version of the framework, the issue is still there. When I run my `NET8` `MAUI` app on an Android device, the `ListView` displays the list of items correctly. When I tap on an item, the background is an orange color, as you see in the following screenshot.

[image]

Is the a way to change the color of the selected item in a `ListView`?

### Update

Under the `Android` folder, I added a new XML file called *style.xml* and set the property to `AndroidResource` (that I forgot before). The content of this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Test.MainTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">
            @android:color/transparent
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Then, I change the `MainActivity.cs` in particular the theme as instructed.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Test.MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | 
                       ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | 
                       ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
```

The result is the same as before.

### Update/2

Here the result: this is the implementation for Android. When I click/select an item, the background is orange and the property `OnCellPropertyChanged` is called only when I go back from the next page.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the issue on `.NET8`. And the issue already has been reported on GitHub- [Android: ListView Item selected color is by default Orange and no property available to change this color #13812](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13812), please continue following the progress.

As a [temporary solution](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13812#issuecomment-1463458812), you can customize the `ViewCell` with `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewCellRenderer`, then overwrite the Android native methods to set the background color for the cell.

**Output:**

[image]

Reference docs:

[Reuse custom renderers in .NET MAUI - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-7.0)

[Customizing a ViewCell - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell)

**Update:**

1. Add `CustomViewCell.cs` in your project folder.

```
public class CustomViewCell : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ViewCell
{
      public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedBackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
          nameof(SelectedBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(CustomViewCell), Colors.White);
        public Color SelectedBackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }
        public CustomViewCell()
        {

        }
}
```

2. In `Platforms/Android` folder, create the platform-specific implementation file `CustomViewCellHandler.cs` :

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using AContext = Android.Content.Context;
using AView = Android.Views.View;
using AViewGroup = Android.Views.ViewGroup;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;

namespace MauiAppListViewTest.Platforms.Android
{
    public class CustomViewCellHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.ViewCellRenderer
    {
        private AView pCellCore;
        private bool pSelected;
        private Drawable pUnselectedBackground;
        protected override AView GetCellCore(Cell item, AView convertView, AViewGroup parent, AContext context)
        {
            pCellCore = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            this.pSelected = false;
            this.pUnselectedBackground = pCellCore.Background;
            return pCellCore;
        }
        protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
            {
                pSelected = !(pSelected);
                if (pSelected)
                {
                    pCellCore.SetBackgroundColor(((CustomViewCell)sender).SelectedBackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
                }
                else
                {
                    pCellCore.SetBackground(this.pUnselectedBackground);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Register your handler like below in the `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
#if ANDROID
using MauiAppListViewTest.Platforms.Android;
#endif

namespace MauiAppListViewTest
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {         
            <!--Omitted for brevity-->
              .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers => {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler<CustomViewCell, CustomViewCellHandler>();
#endif
               });
```

4. Don't forget to setting `SelectedBackgroundColor="Green"` in **XAML**:

```
  <ListView x:Name="lvTest" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CustomViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="Green" >
                    <Grid HeightRequest="44">
                        <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </local:CustomViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

And if you set a breakpoint in the Android implementation: `CustomViewCellHandler` at `e.PropertyName == "IsSelected"` and then click the item of the `ListView`, it'll get there:

[image]

**Update:**
You need also remove the `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` for the `ListView` to get it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. I downloaded the repo and the project is working. When I add to my project only the code for Android, I'm still seeing the orange background. I put a breakpoint in the Android implementation at `e.PropertyName == "IsSelected"` and it is not called at all. I added the definition of the handler in the _MauiProgram_. I copied your code in my project. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Enrico Thanks for your response. Since you haven't provided your demo, I think you've missed some of the key steps to implement it. I've updated the detailed steps on how to get it worked, you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update and yes I have done that in my project. I can't share my project because this is for a client and it is quite big. I'll try to create a demo and replicate my issue

Comment: Also, there is an issue with Windows because if I select an item, the `ItemSelected` is not fired

Comment: Oh it is not related to this one, sorry.

Comment: I still have the issue with the orange background. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: 1. Please follow my workaround which should also work on your side. 2. It's recommended that you try to use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-8.0) instead of `ListView`, and [change selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?view=net-maui-8.0#change-selected-item-color).

Comment: I don't use `CollectionView` because the result is inconsistent with the environment. For example, in Android, when I select an item, I get a nice menu in the menu tab, like other apps. With the `CollectionView` you have to swipe, unusual for Android users.

Comment: @Enrico That's fine, feel free to report here if u got any issues.

Comment: I have just updated the post to show how it works. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the response! @Enrico Do you mean you have figured it out and are able to change the default orange background?

Comment: Absolutely not  As you see in my _Update/2_ the `OnCellPropertyChanged` function is called only when I'm going back from another page. When I tap on an item, the background is still in orange.

Comment: Yes, looks like the property `OnCellPropertyChanged` only get called when navigating back to the listview page, as I said before consider report at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13812.

Comment: I tried on my side, the sample workaround worked but not in my project. I found that after removing CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" and reset selected item to null when I come back in navigation it's better for me. I hope it will help someone.

Comment: @Ragtop59 you were correct. When I removed the `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` is started to work. Thank you all of you

Comment: @Enrico Thanks for your response, I've updated it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, as far as I know, you can either go to your CollectionView and set the SelectionMode to None or you can create a native style and change the Selection colour.

In your CollectionView:

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="None" ..../>
```

Or in your native Android style create a `styles.xml` file and do this:

```
<style name="Test.MainTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And use this theme in your MainActivity

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Test.MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
```

Comment: I get this error `APT2259 'Test.MainTheme' is incompatible with attribute theme (attr) reference`

Comment: Can you update the question with what you have done I have a feeling you have not created the `styles.xml` file correctly, you can also google styles.xml in Android and see how it's done, you need to have an XML attribute and a resource tag. Like shown here https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes#Styles